# Indulge in my stupid and impossible riddle!

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

A situation I made designed to make some sense but requires lateral thinking. Takes place in 2016 but in an alternate universe where we discovered a lot of technology earlier. Say WW2 or so.

> An old man, 91 years old, with one leg sits in his wheelchair, in a white lab. A young blonde rimy man  appears from the SAME room and strangles him to death with his own two hands, with clear anger in his eyes.

What could the reason be?

Edit: Edited this to make it less broad.

Comment: "from the same room"? Isn't the young man (however metaphorical) appearing *in* the white room, in order to be able to strangle the old man? Surely you can't appear *in* a given room *from* that room.

Comment: This was done on purpose, i assure you. It's part of my subtle clues to be able to solve the riddle.

Comment: Is 'more technologically advanced'' important for solving the puzzle?

Comment: Yes. It's crucial. I apologize for the late answer. I have weird timezones and posted this very late

Comment: People are on [se] all over the world (although, obviously, not uniformly distributed), and some are on weird shifts (e.g., up all night), so there are people here 24 hours a day. A bit of advice: you should try to post questions / puzzles only when you will be online for the next hour or two, so you will be able to respond to people.

Comment: If there are really answers 'better than the "real" answer' then I fear you may get your question closed as too broad...

Comment: That could very well happen. Atleast  i gave it a shot. Still getting used to the site and all. I really like the fact that you're all so welcoming and understanding. After today i'll select the answer i think was best since mine is too "out there".

Comment: I have now edited this question to where i have included enough hints. With everything given there is now a solution.

Comment: @beastly-gerbil why did you change 'rimy' to 'grimy'? I'm fairly sure 'rimy' was right, since it is replacing the original 'covered in snow' and in this case it would mean, covered in 'rime' or frost

Comment: @MMAdams oh I thought that was a typo, was fixing the other ones

Comment: Yes. Rimy was indeed not a typo. I apologize for the other typos. English is not my native language. I have proofread it more than once and am confident in every word i chose. Everything i wrote is there for a reason. Not a single thing is there just to "be there".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old man is

> a scientist-inventor, who devised some piece of technology; perhaps, the time machine.

The young man is

> someone from the future.

He is rimy because

> he has just come back in time to this place and this time, and—like the DeLorean of *Back to the Future*—he is frosty from the journey.

And he is strangling the old man because

> the old man's invention (of the time machine?) has turned the young man's present into a place of horror for him, and he has decided to come back and take his revenge by ending the life of the inventor who set the wheels in motion to make his present nightmare a reality.

Answer (score 7):

Is the first old man

> A tree? it is old and has one 'leg' and if it were winter it could 'sit' in a white room

The second young man is

> A blizzard, young because it was just born, made of wind 'covered in snow' and it 'strangles' the tree to death

Answer (score 4):

The interpretation is just literal in that

The young man was pissed at the old man for stealing his wooden leg, covering him in snow, and sitting on him.

I'm picturing the old man as Jasper Beardly on the Simpsons, seems like something he would do and he needs the leg.

Answer (score 2):

This might be totally on the wrong track, but I think...

Old man sitting in a white room is...

> Tobacco in smoking side of a cigarette

One leg is..

> The filter side

Young man covered in snow is the

> Smoke

Strangles him to death is

> The red ring that slowly burns the cigarette

**Metaphor**

> Cigarette actually kills the smoker in long run.

Answer (score 2):

Could be that

> both men are the same person.

Why the room is white?

> It's some kind of hospital

Why the young man kills the old one?

> The old man gets a new leg, getting a new youth. Thus young man replaces the old one "killing" him

Snow?

> The man still has white hair

Answer (score 2):

> The young man was put into some kind of frozen stasis against his will. Seeing the old man who froze him, now much older than he last saw, the young man knows that his loved ones will be old and/or gone, and attacks the old man in a rage.

Comment: On the right track! This will get chosen as best if nothing else pops up.

Answer (score 1):

A technological answer. 
Old man and young man are

> a brand new satellite on an old, consolidated, rocket launcher

Why white room?

> it is intended as a safe place where to mount the satellite upon the rocket ([see this wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_structure#White_room)

Why one leg?

> the rocket stands vertically

Why the young man gives death to the old man?

> Because it will be burn entirely (or fall in the ocean)

Why the word "strangles"?

> Because, in areospace technical terms, a rocket engine does its work only if it *chokes* or it is *choked*. If it is not, the rocket won't lift.

Why covered in snow?

> Usually the fairing structure that contains the satellite covers it and it is white

Answer (score 1):

Literal answer:

> The young man really wants some hot food that the old man has. The old man won't give up his food, so the young man strangles him for it.

Comment: Seems harsh....

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mesh with the 'appears from the same room' part, but:

> The old man is a (maybe antique) hat-stand or similar, the young man, upon coming in from the snow, removes his scarf and wraps it around the stand